# getting a layout to fit some device screen size in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am using a layout as shown below.

Issue

1 - It works fine on most of the devices,  But i cannot see the full layout on

```
- Nexus 5, Sony Xperia Z1, and Galaxy S2
```

In these above devices, I can only see upto Gridview grids . I cannot see the EditText and Button below .

2 - The layout already has a gridview, so I cannot use ScrollView to see the entire layout in smaller screen devices. Hence the above issue is not resolved.

3 - My GridView have an Imageview in it.  when i try to scale the Imageview , it still shows the image on top of the Imageview, even though i put scale as CENTRE_INSIDE.

Kindly help me to fit my layout into smaller screen devices as Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S2, and also larger screen devices as Sony Xperia Z1.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong in my layout xml file.

Note- Important blocks to check are Gridview block and last row Linear layout for Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<include
    android:id="@+id/CustomTitle"
    layout="@layout/custom_title" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/CustomTitle"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Title_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/FavoritesViewRealtiveLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"

        android:layout_marginTop="2dip" >

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_detail"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="@string/Fav_Edit_1"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:textSize="17sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/device_detail"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"            

        android:text="Camera/Encoder" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="NVR/DVR" 
        />

  </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/AddDevice_Name_Bar_TextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:background="#ffffff" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Date_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Title_RelativeLayout"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Layout_detail"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="@string/Fav_Edit_2"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:textSize="17sp" />

                   <Button
             android:id="@+id/division_4_Button"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/Layout_detail"
             android:background="@drawable/div4_layout_mode_selector"
             android:textColor="@drawable/textview_color_selector" />
         <Button
                android:id="@+id/division_9_Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Layout_detail"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/div9_layout_mode_selector"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textview_color_selector" />


       <Button
                android:id="@+id/division_delete_Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Layout_detail"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/div_delete_selector"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textview_color_selector" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/Favorite_GridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Date_RelativeLayout"
       android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"   
        android:listSelector="@drawable/gridview_norecode_selector"
        android:numColumns="3"            

      />
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/AddDevice_Name_Bar_TextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Favorite_GridView"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Ti_RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/AddDevice_Name_Bar_TextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"            
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip" >

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_detail"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="@string/Fav_Edit_3"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:textSize="17sp" />

  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/AddDevice_Name_EditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/device_detail"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="@string/Fav_Edit_4"
                android:inputType="textUri"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="" />

     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/Button_Layout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
      android:layout_below="@id/AddDevice_Name_EditText"
      android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
         android:id="@+id/AddDevice_Save_Btn"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="5dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="@string/Save" />

</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am also attaching the GridView xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
   />   

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Day_TextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gridview_line_norecord"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"        
    android:text="Hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a fundamental problem with having elements below a `GridView`. Normally you can't control how many elements go into the `GridView`, so if you use `wrap_content` for its height, it will expand to accommodate all the items.

Under normal circumstances you would use a `GridView` with either a height of `match_parent`, fixed (x dp) or proportionate (weighted - actually possibly still `match_parent` but included in a weighted container).

Since you have to display items underneath it, the first choice is not really a choice. So you can choose one of the other options.

Comment: Thank you for giving the comment.